# Magento 2 - Manage Stock + ERP - Stock Reservation and Salable Quantity issue

Tags: magento2.3

We have Magento 2.3 integrated with an ERP to manage our stock levels, everything seems to be working fine until we have noticed a problem with products with low stock levels.

Example:

Product 'A' has 20 qty in Magento which is correctly synchronized with the ERP.

An order is placed to buy 10 units of product 'A' in Magento.

Magento creates a stock reservation for 10 units but in a few minutes the ERP will come and deduct the qty from 20 to 10.

Because Magento has 10 reserved now the product shows out of stock in the frontend even though we have 10 available.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You initially have 20 in stock. 10 reservations (your order) + 10 deduction (ERP stock adjustment) means you are out of stock.

Comment: @JonathanRibas The 10 reserved by Magento and the 10 deducted from the ERP is for the same order, I have 10 available and that's the issue.

Comment: Why do you deduct with your ERP if Magento has already done it with reservation?

Comment: @JonathanRibas Because we have more than 5 sales channels such as Amazon, eBay, other websites and we need to sync all the correct quantities.

Comment: You have initially 20 then an order is placed so Magento makes a reservation on 10 qty, it means your saleable quantity is now 10. You don't need to deduct it, it will be automatically deducted when your order is captured.